# Trouble importing multiple CSVs as Rails while maintaining associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord

First post.  Relatively new to Rails and coding in general.

I'm having trouble importing seed data from multiple CSVs into Rails and ensuring that associations are maintained.  Data are data on restaurants and inspections done on those restaurants (restaurants have_many inspections, and inspections belong_to restaurants)

This problem appears similar to 
[Rails CSV import, adding to a related table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827209/rails-csv-import-adding-to-a-related-table), and [Associating rows from uploaded CSV files with a User in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347026/associating-rows-from-uploaded-csv-files-with-a-user-in-rails), and seems related to how the user passes in a new variable in http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-csv-library-part/.

Trying suggested code and variations on it I successfully import data, but restaurant_id is nil in the inspections table, similar to [undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass when trying CSV import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643449/undefined-method-path-for-nilnilclass-when-trying-csv-import).  I am providing a file name for the import code though, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

File code included below - Any thoughts appreciated!

*Inspection Migration*

```
class CreateInspections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :inspections do |t|
      t.integer :inspection_id
      t.belongs_to :restaurant, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.date :date
      t.time :time
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

*Inspection Model*

```
class Inspection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

*Restaurant Migration*

```
class CreateRestaurants < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :restaurants do |t|
        t.text :name
        t.integer :permit_id
        t.text :address
        t.decimal :latitude
        t.decimal :longitude

        t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

*Restaurant Model:*

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :inspections
end
```

*Inspection CSV:*

```
inspection_id,permit_id,date,time
```

*Restaurant CSV:*

```
permit_id,name,address,latitude,longitude
```

*Seeds.rb*

```
require 'csv'
#import restaurant records  
csv_text = File.read('db/restaurants.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  Restaurant.create!(row.to_hash)
end

#import inspection records
csv_text = File.read('db/inspections.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  inspection = Inspection.create!(row.to_hash.except("permit_id"))
  inspection.restaurant = Restaurant.find_by(permit_id: row["permit_id"])
end
```

I have excluded "permit_id" from the import of inspection data because, as I understand it, active record is going to create a field "restaurant_id" in the database table instead and use that for the association.  I've tried a number of variations on the block to get the value for restaurants_id, including nested loops and a separate block to get it and append it, but no success at this point though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assigning the `restaurant` in memory doesn't update the database. There are two ways to fix this:

Save after the assignment:

```
csv.each do |row|
  inspection = Inspection.create!(row.to_hash.except("permit_id"))
  inspection.restaurant = Restaurant.find_by(permit_id: row["permit_id"])
  inspection.save!
end
```

Include `restaurant` in the `create!` parameters:

```
csv.each do |row|
  restaurant = Restaurant.find_by(permit_id: row["permit_id"])
  inspection = Inspection.create!(
    row.to_hash.except("permit_id").merge(restaurant: restaurant)
  )
end
```

Comment: Also - regarding the two options provided above, is there any difference in performance if dealing with large datasets?

Comment: Using `create!` will be more efficient. In both cases, you have a query for `Restaurant.find` and another for `Inspection.create!`, but `save!` adds a third query you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `inspection.restaurant` but it looks like you aren't saving the updated record.